# How do I remotely modify a Windows 10 hosts file?

Tags: windows, dns, script, hosts, patch

I have a general email issue, with the solution being to edit the `hosts` file through `notepad`, however I was wondering if there is a way to patch the `hosts` file remotely, changing an IP within it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: I work in IT Dept.

Comment: {shrug}. It's still off topic.

Comment: This could be on topic at [sf] but has probably already been answered several times. use the built in site search. https://serverfault.com/search If you do ask there then you should specify what kind of controls and operating systems you have. Can you push files out via Group Policy? Are the machines on a domain? What kind of Domain Controller do you have? And so on. As it stands your question is vague and provides no information on what you've tried.